# Postgres left nested join with having count condition items

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have 3 tables:

```sh
users - id
huddles - id, host_id, title, min_persons
huddle_guests - id, huddle_id, user_id
```

I want to count user huddles which have more or same huddle guests as huddle min_persons.

This query returns users with huddles count:

```sql
select u.id, count(h.id)
from users u
left join huddles h
on h.host_id = u.id
left join huddle_guests hg
on hg.huddle_id = h.id
group by u.id
```

I tried to add `having`:

```sql
select u.id, count(h.id)
from users u
left join huddles h
on h.host_id = u.id
left join huddle_guests hg
on hg.huddle_id = h.id
group by u.id
having count(hg.id) + 1 >= h.min_persons
```

It gives me error:

```
ERROR:  column "h.min_persons" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 8: having count(hg.id) + 1 >= h.min_persons
```

If I add `h.min_persons` to `group by`, the count number is incorrect (same number as without having)

Sample data example:

```
users
id
1
2

huddles
id, host_id, title, min_persons
1, 1, 'u1-h1', 2
2, 1, 'u1-h2', 2
3, 2, 'u2-h1', 3

huddle_guests
id, huddle_id, user_id
1, 1, 2
2, 3, 1
```

Should return:

```
user id, huddles count
1, 1
2, 0
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results wouldhelp.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added sample data example, keep in mind I count guests + 1 (host included), as shown in my query above

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of persons per huddle using:

```
select h.*, count(*) as num_persons
from huddle_guests hg join
     huddles h
     on hg.huddle_id = h.id
group by h.id;
```

(Yes, Postgres and Standard SQL allow this syntax with `select h.*` and `group by h.id` assuming that `huddles(id)` is the primary key of `huddles`.)

Then you can use a `having` clause to do what you want:

```
select h.*, count(*) as num_persons
from huddle_guests hg join
     huddles h
     on hg.huddle_id = h.id
group by h.id;
having count(*) > h.min_persons + 1;
```

You don't need the `users` table unless you need additional columns.  The `host_id` seems to be the column you want.

EDIT:

To show users with zero huddles:

```
select u.id, count(*) as num_persons
from users u left join
     huddle_guests hg
     on hg.host_id = u.id left join
     huddles h
     on hg.huddle_id = h.id
group by u.id;
having count(*) > h.min_persons + 1 or
       count(hg.host_id) = 0;
```

Comment: Yes, last query would show correct number. Is it possible to combine it with users table? (I need to show all users, even with 0 huddles, without code outside sql side - last query will show only users with huddles)

Comment: @Vlad . . . That is a good reason to include the `users` table.